# Angular build prod error

Tags: angular, angular5

I have a build error when trying to build to prod. using ng build --prod angular 5
property does not exists. why is this?

`<input placeholder="Name of Registrant." name="Name"  [(ngModel)]="formA.Name" name="Name">`

Comment: post some code please

Comment: Sorry, but your code doesn't have anything to do with your error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a guess, but I think you are writing your variable definitions as this: `Amt: any[];` in your `tables.component.html`.  Try refactoring your variable definitions to this:

```
Amt: any = [];
AmtPay: any = [];
AmtPayAftone: any = [];
AmyPayA: any = [];
...
```

Comment: that did not work. maybe, and what you think should I try `export interface form{}` this is how I am using these variables. ` [(ngModel)]="formData.Amt"`